# Why do I get a 502 error while uploading a file in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I was trying to upload large files into my ASP.NET Core Web API. I am able to upload small sized files.

But when I try to upload larger files, I'm getting an error 502 after waiting for more than 10 minutes.

To make the API support large files, I added a `web.config` file to the Web API project and added these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore
        requestTimeout="00:20:00"
        processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
        arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
        stdoutLogEnabled="false"
        stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
        forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="staging" />
            <!-- value could be "development", "staging" or "production"-->
        </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097152000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But still, it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939)?

Comment: yes i tried , getting 502 error

Answer (score 0):

Add RequestFormLimits on the function that you are using for file upload. Check below code:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
public IActionResult UploadFile()
{
}
```